PDF viewer (with zoom and performance) in MAUI/Blazor with
I am trying to show a simple PDF in our web view based MAUI app on an Android device. It's seems harder than necessary. A version with canvas does work, but performance is terrible.
Internet and AI suggests PDF.js as solution and using a WebView as base. However, it always shows as a white blank view when running. Also, Visual Studio for Mac also marks the WebView (or BlazorWebView) as unavailable making me think it just ignores this tag.
The warning is: "Found markup element with unexpected name 'BlazorWebViewHostPage'. If this is intended
to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace"
@page "/pdfviewer"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui
@inject TemporaryFileService TemporaryFileService
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@using ProjectNameMobileMaui.Services

<BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
    <BlazorWebViewHostPage>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>PDF Viewer</title>
            <base href="_content/YourAssemblyName/" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <app>Loading...</app>
            <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
</BlazorWebViewHostPage>
<BlazorWebView Source="/pdfViewer.html?filePath=/sample.pdf" />
</BlazorWebView>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    private string FilePath;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnParametersSet called");
        var uri = Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri(Navigation.Uri);
        var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
        FileName = query["fileName"];
        Console.WriteLine($"FileName parameter: {FileName}");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
        {
            FilePath = Path.Combine(TemporaryFileService.GetTempDirectory(), FileName);
            Console.WriteLine($"Calculated FilePath: {FilePath}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FileName parameter is null or empty");
        }
    }
}

Any leads?
Parts of my csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SkipValidateMauiImplicitPackageReferences>true</SkipValidateMauiImplicitPackageReferences>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>3</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>
      <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.40" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.40" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.5.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" Version="8.0.40" />
    </ItemGroup>

And pdfViewer.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDF Viewer</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #pdfContainer {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            touch-action: none;
        }

        canvas {
            touch-action: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.10.377/pdf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pdfContainer">PDF Viewer Loaded</div>
    <script>console.log("PDF Viewer script started");
        document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += "<br>Script Started";

        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const filePath = urlParams.get('filePath');
        console.log(`filePath from URL: ${filePath}`);
        document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += `<br>filePath from URL: ${filePath}`;

        if (!filePath) {
            console.error('No file path found');
            document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += "<br>No file path found";
        } else {
            fetch(filePath)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("Fetch response received, status:", response.status);
                    document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += `<br>Fetch response status: ${response.status}`;
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
                    }
                    return response.arrayBuffer();
                })
                .then(pdfData => {
                    console.log("PDF data loaded");
                    document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += "<br>PDF data loaded";
                    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.10.377/pdf.worker.min.js';

                    return pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData }).promise;
                })
                .then(pdf => {
                    console.log("PDF document loaded");
                    document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += "<br>PDF document loaded";
                    return pdf.getPage(1);
                })
                .then(page => {
                    console.log("PDF page loaded");
                    document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += "<br>PDF page loaded";
                    const scale = 1.5;
                    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

                    const container = document.getElementById('pdfContainer');
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;
                    container.appendChild(canvas);

                    const renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: context,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };
                    return page.render(renderContext).promise;
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("PDF page rendered");
                    document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += "<br>PDF page rendered";
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error loading PDF:', error);
                    document.getElementById('pdfContainer').innerHTML += `<br>Error loading PDF: ${error.message}`;
                });
        }</script>
</body>
</html>


Update
Tried this guide https://youtu.be/dfspSeE9AVk?si=gnTBwUVLuoirwfWd without success:
The errors I get now are:
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(381)] "Warning: Setting up fake worker.", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.js (381)
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(40018)] "Uncaught TypeError: pattern.at is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js (40018)
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(40018)] "Uncaught TypeError: pattern.at is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js (40018)
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(910)] "An error occurred while loading the PDF.
[chromium] 
[chromium] PDF.js v3.11.174 (build: ce8716743)
[chromium] Message: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot read property 'WorkerMessageHandler' of undefined".", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.js (910)
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(1927)] "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot read property 'WorkerMessageHandler' of undefined".", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.js (1927)

I've tried both the newest version (4.3.136) and the last 3.x version. I've also tried the legacy version of the 3.x version.

You have tried this i am guessing https://youtu.be/dfspSeE9AVk?si=gnTBwUVLuoirwfWd

No, I have not tried that approach. Seems to be different from what I've tried. Did not download any framework. Will try this and get back to you!

Have followed that guide now have a lot of issues there. Have updated the question.
